# Rewrite URL based on variable

Tags: php, url-rewriting

I need to add a variable of the username to all of my URL's when the user is logged in.

So for example it would be:

- www.example.com/?user=user1
- www.example.com/category1/product1/?user=user1

The reason I need to add the variable is for sending the page to a PDF service as each user has a unique style to their template.

I have my variable set but how can I rewrite the page URL to include the variable if it isn't already included on the URL using php?

Comment: Why do you want to do it via php? Shouldn't you try some webserver configuration?

Comment: Is the PHP application that has the user's credentials the same as the one that generates the PDF?  If so, you might consider using a session object instead of URL injection.

Comment: If you absolutely must use php, could you use a HTTP 301 redirect?

Comment: @PaulProgrammer unfortunately not, using a wordpress install which generates user credentials and and external service for PDFing

Comment: Is the url with the variable supposed to trigger a redirect?

Answer (score 1):

Apache can't know if the user is logged in, it concerns your PHP code. In this case, I think the best solution is to add a SESSION variable like :

```
$_SESSION['user'] = 'user1';
```

And instead of check if the user parameter exists, you will have to check if the $_SESSION['user'] exists. That will be easier and safer.

Answer (score 0):

What you're looking for isn't actually php, it's an apache module in your .htaccess file.  This is the best blog I've seen on the subject: http://www.addedbytes.com/articles/for-beginners/url-rewriting-for-beginners/

Comment: This only works if apache knows about the user credentials, which it may not if user management is done in the application.

Comment: why? "?user=user1" is just a string in the initial url that remains unchanged in the final url.  It can be simply regexed like any other part of the url

Comment: I read that OP wants to add the `?user=user1` to the URL, which isn't there when it appears in Apache.